# UpdatePanel with UploadFile control doesnt work well

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, file-upload, updatepanel

I've three images. I use javascript to mark which one is selected. After user clicks on one I change its class to active. its `<li><a>`. Now when I wasn't using updatepanel after form post I could see from code behind which element is active and it was correct. After adding updatePanel which contains entire form after postback which should refresh content of updatePanel value is wrong and active is always set to default first `<a>`. Whats more in this updatePanel there is UploadFile control which doesn't work well because it always has HasFile value to false even though I choose file.

Thanks You for any hints

Comment: Why you are happy about "UpdatePanel with UploadFile control doesnt work well ':)'" ? :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form must be a full postback. You have to add a Trigger for the Full postback, if your FileUpload control is in the update panel.

Alternatively if you want to upload Asynchronously , you could try AJAX `AsyncFileUpload` control
http://asp.net-informations.com/ajax/ajax-AsyncFileUpload.htm

Comment: My Fileupload control is inside a user control and I'm getting FileUpload.PostedFile=""

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known problem, please take a look into the following article:
http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2008/04/01/file-upload-in-updatepanel-asp.net-ajax.aspx

Comment: site no longer works